# Unit testing reducers, test each slice reducer or combined reducer?

Tags: unit-testing, redux

Suppose I have a reducer file reducers/group1.js like this

```
export default combineReducers({
  A: combineReducers({ A1, A2 }),
  B: reducerB,
  C: reducerC
})
```

Is there any difference between testing each slice reducer (A1, A2, reducerB and reducerC) and testing the combined one?

```
import group1 from 'reducers/group1'

describe('reducers', () => {
  describe('group1', () => {
    it('should provide the initial state', () => {
      expect(group1(undefined, {})).to.equal({ group1: { A: { ... }, B: ... } })
    })

    it(...)

    // ...
  })
})
```

or

```
import { A1, A2, reducerB, reducerC } from 'reducers/group1'

describe('reducers', () => {
  describe('group1', () => {
    describe('A1', () => {
      it('should provide the initial state', () => {
        expect(A1(undefined, {})).to.equal(0) // if A1 is just a number
      })
    })
    describe('A2', () => { ... })
    describe('reducerB', () => { ... })
    describe('reducerC', () => { ... })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is usually better because it allows for simpler unit tests. I can imagine a scenario where a developer might want to write a bunch of tests for reducer `C` without knowing anything about reducers `A` and `B`. The second code sample allows for that developer to write a suite of `C` tests without being concerned about what `A` or `B` even are. It also helps when rewriting tests if a reducer's behavior is drastically changed: all those tests live in one place instead of being scattered all over the test file.

However, there might be some instances where you want to write a test for the entire reducer. For example, if you have a global reset action, you would want to test that the entire reducer properly responds to that action instead of writing an individual test for each reducer. Most of the time it's probably going to be cleaner to write tests for individual reducers though.